How do I change the OpenIddict client settings when a user tries to log in?
I am trying to implement an OpenIddict client that logs in with Entra, and I have got it working by setting up the client at Startup.cs, where I put in my client details (clientId, clientSecret, tenantId). One of the features I am making is allowing the admin to change these details at runtime and not have to restart the whole server every time these changes are applied.
I have gotten to the point that I can use the built-in callbacks to change the clientId and clientSecret, but changing the tenantId has been proving very difficult. Anyone has run into this issue before?
openIddictBUilder.AddClient(options =>
  options.AddEventHandler<OpenIddictClientEvents.PrepareConfigurationRequestContext>(config =>
    {
      config.UseInlineHandler(async (context) =>
        {
          //change the details here
          var settings = await settingService.getSettings();
          context.Registration.ClinetId = settings.clientId;
          context.Registration.ClientSecret = settings.clientSecret;
          // What do i do with the tenant?
        }
    }
    // more boilerplate code here
    var providers = options.UseWebProviders().AddMicrosoft(options => 
    {
      options.SetClientId("placeholderId")
        .setClientSecret("placeholderSecret")
        .setRedirectUri("callback/login/microsoft")
        .SetTenant("placeholderTenant");
    }
  }
}
 

